# Automating Facebook Login with Selenium Webdriver

Tags: facebook, facebook-graph-api, selenium, selenium-webdriver, webdriver

I am looking to introduce Facebook login/sign up tests into a Webdriver suite for a C# application.

Facebook Developers has [an article on manual verification](https://developers.facebook.com/docs/facebook-login/testing-your-login-flow/), but does not seem to reference any procedure for automating these tests. I could simply write the steps indicated but I would like to avoid running scripts on the Facebook UI, especially when it involves creating test users.

Looking through a few previous answers, it appears that Facebook had an automation solution a few years ago, but I can no longer find any reference to it anywhere.

Has anyone had any experience automating Facebook Connect login or sign up? Any tips or strategies you can share would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: Signing into Facebook is really just filling in various fields and then clicking a button. You can either Google how to accomplish this by the various walk-throughs available online for signing into e-mail or you can just Google the individual steps. Unless I'm totally misunderstanding you here?

Comment: @Seanny123 The problem's not with actually automating the UI, I can do that fine. It's more about a scalable approach to it - I don't want to create a new Facebook account every time I release to test sign up through Connect.

Comment: Yep, totally missed that. I thought I was mis-interpreting your question and you've confirmed it for me. My bad.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The first thing you probably want to do is create test users.

The Facebook API lets you do this easily;

https://developers.facebook.com/docs/graph-api/reference/v2.0/app/accounts/test-users

This will give you a login url which should result in automatic login and as result drop a cookie which should help you avoid manual login within your application.

The api also allows you to create relationships and publish events

Comment: I think this is what I'm looking for in the first instance. Thanks @robbiewareham

Answer (score 1):

You can connect to Facebook by logging in automatically using Selenium, I wrote it in Java.

It roughly looks like this:

```
void login()
{
    if(isElementFound(EMAIL_FIELD))
        driver.findElement(EMAIL_FIELD).sendKeys(username);
    if(isElementFound(PWD_FIELD))
        driver.findElement(PWD_FIELD).sendKeys(password);
    if(isElementFound(LOGIN_BUTTON))
        driver.findElement(LOGIN_BUTTON).click();
    if(waitForElement(MENU, 30))
        System.out.println("login Successful");
    else
        System.out.println("login un-successful");       
}
```

Answer (score 1):

```
@Test
public void facebookLogin() throws Exception {

    WebDriver driver = getDriver();
    driver.get("http://www.facebook.com");

    WebElement email = driver.findElement(By.name("email"));
    email.clear();
    email.sendKeys("myuser");

    WebElement password = driver.findElement(By.name("pass"));
    password.clear();
    password.sendKeys("mypass");

    WebElement loginbutton = driver.findElement(By.id("loginbutton"));
    loginbutton.click();

    System.out.println("done!");
}
```

Answer (score 0):

When I needed to do this, the option of creating test users was not sufficient - they were too short lived and we needed time to populate them with a particular set of attributes.

We ended up setting up servers that mocked the parts of the Facebook APIs that were exercised in our tests. We then redirected the test environment to resolve the facebook domain names to our those servers. It was not easy, but this approach had several advantages

1. We could populate the users as we pleased without worrying about them disappearing
2. We could have as many as we wanted
3. We could control the performance of the FB APIs - and capture metrics on that performance during the test. If something was slow, we could be sure it wasn't a FB hiccup. If we wanted to test what happened to the target app if FB got slow, we could do that, too.

Comment: This sounds really interesting, I'd love to get more information on how you did it. Have you written it up anywhere?