# Selenium, browser perf, and social login

Tags: facebook, node.js, selenium, browserstack

I have a web app that is wrapped with a social login scheme (Facebook and twitter). I'm currently setting up some selenium tests through the NPM module [browser-perf](https://github.com/axemclion/browser-perf), and I noticed that there is a `preScript` that can be run for performing authentication, etc. Here is the example script the docs give:

```
{
    preScript: function(browser) {
        return function(browser) {
            return browser.get(cfg.page).then(function() {
                console.log('Filling in Username');
                return browser.elementByCssSelector('.UsernameClass')
            }).then(function(el) {
                return el.type('Username for site');
            }).then(function() {
                console.log('Filling in Password');
                return browser.elementByCssSelector('.PasswordFieldClass');
            }).then(function(el) {
                return el.type(cfg.password.val);
            }).then(function() {
                return browser.elementByCssSelector('.SubmitButton');
            }).then(function(el) {
                console.log('Clicking submit');
                return el.click();
            }).then(function() {
                return browser.sleep(5000);
            });
        }
    }
}
```

I was thinking about how I could apply this to my web app, but the only problem is, when the Facebook or Twitter login buttons are clicked, a new window is popped up and control is taken away from the original script. In a normal use case, the user would fill in their info, click login, and control would be returned.

Is there a way to handle this with automated selenium tests? Can I somehow grab a reference to the pop up window?

Answer (score 0):

This explains how to create test Facebook accounts and use them to drop a session cookie so that you do not need to worry about the popup as it will not be displayed

[Automating Facebook Login with Selenium Webdriver](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23727794/automating-facebook-login-with-selenium-webdriver/23731561#23731561)

Answer (score 0):

You can grab references to a new windows using wd.newWindow, as referred to in these docs - https://github.com/admc/wd/blob/master/doc/api.md

You would just have to modify this script to click on the login button, grab a handle to the new window, run the login script and you should be good.